# Log4Net files to database

Tags: c#, log4net, bulkinsert, bcp

So, I have been stuck on the below mentioned issue for more than a day now and am dead confused on how can I go about it.

My boss wants the logs generated by Log4Net, into the database (currently they are being generated in flat files). But hey, he does not want Log4Net to log it directly to the database (which is easy to do :)), as it would be an overhead leading to increased latency.

His requirement is, once the log files are generated, these files should be bulk inserted/copied/imported into the database.

Does anyone have any tips or suggestions I could use?

Note: The lines in the log file are not consistent, most of the times it starts with Date. But at times if there was an exception the Line starts with System.IO.Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this based on the information available from your question

You could just have workers/background processes running (periodically or whenever file updates depending on how much log loss you can tolerate) which would consume this file(s), parse them (you will have to do this regardless, since the files are custom to you and store them in db as you want. Since they are read only operations you will not face any concurrency issues while reading them. Although you will face this issue when writing to your db.

Comment: Thank you Monil.... However, these are not custom files... Log4Net has a pretty standard format in generating log files I believe.

Comment: Are you looking for parser? Are you looking for the code for background process? Are you looking for entire existing solution?

Comment: I was looking for something like bcp... or on similar lines.

Comment: Additionally, if there is a way to do it as a batch process... I might be fine with that too...

Comment: You could write one. However I am not aware of an existing solution.

Comment: No worries... Thank you for trying Monil